# Include Location And Company on Careers RSS Feed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, feed

The RSS Feed on careers.stackoverflow.com currently returns an xml like this one:

```
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/88105/senior-net-developer-clearcost-health</guid>
    <link>http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/88105/senior-net-developer-clearcost-health</link>
    <category>c#</category>
    <category>sql-server</category>
    <category>javascript</category>
    <category>ajax</category>
    <category>asp.net-mvc</category>
    <title>Senior .NET Developer at ClearCost Health (San Francisco, CA) (allows remote)</title>
    <description><p><span><span>ClearCost Health is looking for a Senior Microsoft .Net developer. &nbsp;This person will be a member of the product development team and will take a leadership role in design and programming to support application development and implementation projects. &nbsp;The position reports to the CTO.</span></span></p><br /><p><span>As a member of the development team, the Sr. .Net Developer will be responsible for developing .Net applications to support product development, implementation and other business/technical requirements. &nbsp;Responsibilities will include designing, programming, and testing web applications as well as planning, requirements analysis, data analysis, and documenting solutions for assigned project.</span></p></description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 13 May 2015 05:31:55 Z</pubDate>
    <a10:updated>2015-05-13T05:31:55Z</a10:updated>
</item>
```

Could you include the jobs' company name and location (city, state or coordinates)?

Comment: It's already in the title... {JobTitle} at {Company} ({Location})

Comment: Yes, it is. However, I feel like a job's company name and location are important enough to warrant their own property. It would make that job representation more useful. Say you want to do something with that data; you'd have to parse out the location from the title, which granted, is not a super big deal, but what happens if you decide to change the format of the title to something like {jobTitle} - {Location} ({Company})? Whatever clients depend on the old format are now broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the feed so that a single item looks like this:

```
<item xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <guid isPermaLink="true">https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/62162/ad-server-technology-developer-stack-exchange</guid>
  <link>https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/62162/ad-server-technology-developer-stack-exchange</link>
  <a10:author>
    <a10:name>Stack Exchange</a10:name>
  </a10:author>
  <category>c#</category>
  <category>sql</category>
  <category>redis</category>
  <category>javascript</category>
  <title>Ad Server Technology Developer at Stack Exchange (New York, NY, United States) (allows remote)</title>
  <description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Come help us build an all-new advertising platform serving tens of millions of impressions on Stack Overflow each day. We try to match every user's unique location and interests with jobs on Stack Overflow Careers, and serve them relevant ads, all in about 10 milliseconds. In just a few months, our team has already improved click-throughs by almost 30%, but there are still big challenges, and we're looking for smart, passionate people to help us solve them. You'll work on designing and implement new advertising types (not just job ads), new targeting algorithms, new analytics tracking and analysis tools, solve performance problems, support multiple active data centers, and integrate with our other products.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;We want to hire the right person wherever you are in the world. If you&amp;rsquo;re in New York or interested in relocating to our office, you&amp;rsquo;ll enjoy some amazing amenities like private offices and in-house chefs. If not, we&amp;rsquo;ll help you create your dream office at home, wherever that might be.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</description>
  <pubDate>Wed, 20 May 2015 20:45:55 Z</pubDate>
  <a10:updated>2015-05-20T20:45:55Z</a10:updated>
  <location>New York, NY, United States</location>
</item>
```

Note the `location` and `author` elements. It'll go out to production in the next push (build 2913).